# Toggle Plus / Minus single Button to show and hide table

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#t1").hide(); // hide table by default
  $('#sp1').on('click', function() {
    $("#t1").show();
  });
  $('#close').on('click', function() {
    $("#t1").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-12 col-12 table-responsive">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 10px !important;" align="center">
      <div class="form-group">Main heading</div>
    </div>
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="lbbg3">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 800px;">Sub heading 1</td>
          <td>Sub heading 2</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="background: #eef7fc; text-align: left;" colspan="2">
            <button class="table-plus-btn table1" id="sp1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button><button class="table-minus-btn" id="close"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> Child Heading
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div class="table1shw">
              <table class="table1 table-hover" id="t1">
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
                    Row 1
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                      <a href="#doc">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadio50" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy edu docbtn" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio50" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="valueChanged()"></label>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
                    Row 2
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                      <input type="radio" id="customRadio51" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy" />
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio51" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi, Currently i am using two button Plus and minus, Just i need to display at time one button. when the plus button click the hidden table will get displayed and minus button should appear and plus button is hide. same for the minus button too. more we can say toggle button. also required can we display at time only one hidden table.

All the code and table currently working fine i used this method for accordion but not used for table.

Answer (score 2):

also you can write it a bit shorter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#t1, #close").hide();
  $('#sp1, #close').on('click', function() {
    $('#t1, .table-plus-btn, .table-minus-btn').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide / show buttons based on the click. I added the function toggleButtons(show) where show is equal to if you want to show or hide the row.

```
function toggleButtons(show) {
      if (show) {
        $("#sp1").hide();
        $("#close").show();
      } else {
        $("#sp1").show();
        $("#close").hide();
      }
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#t1").hide(); // hide table by default
  $('#sp1').on('click', function() {
    toggleButtons(true)
    $("#t1").show();
  });
  $('#close').on('click', function() {
    toggleButtons(false)
    $("#t1").hide();
  });
  
  
  function toggleButtons(show) {
      if (show) {
        $("#sp1").hide();
        $("#close").show();
      } else {
        $("#sp1").show();
        $("#close").hide();
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-12 col-12 table-responsive">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 10px !important;" align="center">
      <div class="form-group">Main heading</div>
    </div>
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="lbbg3">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 800px;">Sub heading 1</td>
          <td>Sub heading 2</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="background: #eef7fc; text-align: left;" colspan="2">
            <button class="table-plus-btn table1" id="sp1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            <button class="table-minus-btn" id="close" style="display: none"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> 
            Child Heading
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div class="table1shw">
              <table class="table1 table-hover" id="t1">
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
                    Row 1
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                      <a href="#doc">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadio50" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy edu docbtn" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio50" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="valueChanged()"></label>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
                    Row 2
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                      <input type="radio" id="customRadio51" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy" />
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio51" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken this is what you want to do:
First - Display the plus button, and hide the table
Second- When plus button is clicked display the table, hide the plus button, and show the minus button
Third- When the minus button is clicked, hide the minus button, show the plus button, and hide the table.

It seems that you're code isn't working BECAUSE you are not hiding/displaying the buttons at the appropriate time. I am also assuming only one button should be shown at a time?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#t1").hide(); // hide table by default
        $("#close").hide(); //hide the minus button as well if you only want one button to display at a time

  $('#sp1').on('click', function() { //when plus button is clicked
    $("#t1").show(); 
    $("#sp1").hide(); //you need to hide the plus button now
    $("#close").show(); //and then display the minus button
  });
  $('#close').on('click', function() { 
    $("#t1").hide(); //hide table
    $("#close").hide(); //hide minus btn
    $("#sp1").show(); //show plus button
  });
});
```

Comment: suppose if use this for two row and both the row i do not want to open at the this time only one row will open and second one go off. how this can i do.

Comment: your code is working fine thanks for your help

Comment: You would do the same, show one table and then when the plus button is clicked show the other. When the minus button is clicked, hide the second table.

Comment: here is used like this script but the first table still is open till the time i will not click the minus one. i need the above table will go disappear once the second plus button will clicked on

Comment: So you want both tables to be hidden and one table should display when the plus sign is clicked, and the other should display when the plus sign is clicked again?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#t2").hide(); // hide table by default
  $('#sp2').on('click', function() {
       toggleButtons(true);
    $("#t2").show();
  });
  $('#close2').on('click', function() {
       toggleButtons(false)
    $("#t2").hide();
  });
      function toggleButtons(show) {
      if (show) {
        $("#sp2").hide();
        $("#close2").show();
      } else {
        $("#sp2").show();
        $("#close2").hide();
      }
  }
});

Comment: Since that is another question, please add a new question for this. I have answered your first question so please mark that with the checkmark so it's easier for others to find the answer.